# Binding .NET Core Json to simple parameters

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, binding

I used to just post simple json objects to ASP.NET MVC controllers and the binding engine would parse the body out into the method's simple parameters:

```
{
    "firstname" : "foo",
    "lastname" : "bar"
}
```

and I could have a MVC controller like this:

```
public method Blah(string firstname, string lastname) {}
```

And `firstname` and `lastname` would automatically be pulled from the Json object and mapped to the simple parameters.

I've moved a backend piece to .NET Core 5.0 with the same method signatures, however, when I post the same simple JSON object, my parameters are null. I even tried doing `[FromBody]` on each parameter but they would still be null. It wasn't until I created an extra class that contained the parameter names would the model binding work:

```
public class BlahRequest
{
    public string firstname { get; set;}
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have to update my method signature to look like this:

```
public method Blah([FromBody]BlahRequest request) { }
```

And now, the request has the properties `firstname` and `lastname` filled out from the post request.

Is there a model binder setting where I can go back to binding from a simple Json object to the method's parameters? Or do I have to update all my method signatures to contain a class with properties?

**How the web api method is called**

The original application is written in Angular but I can recreate it with a simple Fiddler request:

```
POST https://localhost:5001/Blah/Posted HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

{"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar"}
```

In previous versions of the .Net framework, the controller's method would parse those values automatically.  Now, on core, it requires a model to be passed in.  I've tried application/json, multipart/form-data, and application/x-www-form-urlencoded as the Content-type and they all end up with null values.

**Smallest .Net Core project**

```
public class Startup {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
        services.AddControllers();
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}

[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class BlahController : ControllerBase {
    public object Posted(string firstname, string lastname) {
        Console.WriteLine(firstname);
        Console.WriteLine(lastname);
        return true;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this? I have a similar issue where I am trying to port .NET Framework code where I have many controller methods like this `public method Blah(string firstname, string lastname) {}` and I am trying to pass JSON in the format `{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Smith"}` and the method won't bind them unless I add an intermediate model

Comment: @Campbell Yup, I did.  The answer I posted below was what I used to port .Net Framework 4.8 code to .Net Core without needing to rewrite the calls from the UI.  Not sure of why it got downvoted, but if you add this provider during the Startup of your .NET core application, this code works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking into the guts of the .Net core source code, I was able to find an example of how the form values provider worked and then reverse engineered a solution for this project.  I think if one was starting fresh, they wouldn't have to solve this problem, but we are moving an existing UI built on Angular onto this new backend on .Net core and didn't want to rewrite all the server side calls as models with the parameters of the methods on the controllers.

So, just to review, in previous versions of .Net, you could post a Json object to an Mvc controller with multiple parameters in the method signature.

```
public object GetSalesOrders(string dashboardName, int fillableState = 0){}
```

and a simple method to call this would like the following:

```
POST https://localhost:5001/api/ShippingDashboard/GetSalesOrders HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{"dashboardName":"/shippingdashboard/bigshipping","fillableState":1}
```

Looking into value providers, I created my own value provider and pushed it to the top of the list during the configuration of the Startup class.

```
services
.AddControllers( options =>{
  options.ValueProviderFactories.Insert(0, new JsonBodyValueProviderFactory());
 })
```

JsonBodyValueProviderFactory is a factory class I wrote.  It inspects the request and if the content type is application/json, it will add a provider to the content:

```
public class JsonBodyValueProviderFactory : IValueProviderFactory{
public Task CreateValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context) {
    if (context == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    var request = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request;
    if (request.HasJsonContentType()) {
        // Allocating a Task only when the body is json data
        return AddValueProviderAsync(context);
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private static async Task AddValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context) {
    var request = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request;
    var body = "";
    Dictionary<string,object> asDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    try {
        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(request.Body)){
            body = await  stream.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        var obj = JObject.Parse(body);
        foreach(var item in obj.Children()){
            asDict.Add(item.Path, item.Values().First());
        }
        
    } catch (InvalidDataException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    var valueProvider = new JsonBodyValueProvider(BindingSource.Form, asDict);
    context.ValueProviders.Add(valueProvider);
}
```

}

Since I don't always know the shape of the data, I utilized Json.Net's JObject and suck the Json body into a JObject.  I then use the top level properties and add them to a dictionary for easy lookup.

The actual class that takes the values and responds to the parameter name is JsonBodyValueProvider:

```
public class JsonBodyValueProvider : BindingSourceValueProvider, IEnumerableValueProvider {
private readonly Dictionary<string, object> values;
private PrefixContainer? _prefixContainer;

public JsonBodyValueProvider( BindingSource bindingSource, Dictionary<string,object> values) : base(bindingSource) {
    if (bindingSource == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingSource));
    }
    if (values == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));
    }
    this.values = values;
}
protected PrefixContainer PrefixContainer {
    get {
        if (_prefixContainer == null) {
            _prefixContainer = new PrefixContainer(values.Keys);
        }
        return _prefixContainer;
    }
}
public override bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix) {
    return PrefixContainer.ContainsPrefix(prefix);
}
public virtual IDictionary<string, string> GetKeysFromPrefix(string prefix) {
    if (prefix == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(prefix));
    }

    return PrefixContainer.GetKeysFromPrefix(prefix);
}
public override ValueProviderResult GetValue(string key){
    if (key == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
    }

    if (key.Length == 0) {
        return ValueProviderResult.None;
    }

    var _values = values[key];
    if (!values.ContainsKey(key)) {
        return ValueProviderResult.None;
    } else {
        return new ValueProviderResult(_values.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

This is pretty much a carbon copy of the FormValueProvider in .Net Core, I just adjusted it to work with a dictionary of input values.

Now my controllers can stay the same from prior versions of .Net without changing method signatures.

Comment: Thanks so much. I am in the same situation & it works very well. Just if anyone want they can initialize Dictionary like this if they want to ignore the possibility of running in error e.g. Action Method has `string userName` & client is passing `username`. So, `Dictionary<string,object> asDict = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` This can help resolve unwanted dictionary no element found errors.

Comment: This might be a dumb but related follow on question.. I am having problems 'porting' `RoutePrefix` and `PrefixContainer` is not clear to me how it's populated for a particular controller.. Is this even the right container to replace the old `RoutePrefix` Attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content type. You must be using application/json content type. This is why you have to create a viewmodel and to add [FromBody] attribute

```
public method Blah([FromBody]BlahRequest request) { }
```

but if you use application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data form enctype or ajax content-type then this will be working

```
public method Blah(string firstname, string lastname) {}
```

if you still have some problems, it means that you are using ApiController. In this case add this code to startup

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
    });
```

Comment: Tried changing the request header's content to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and also tried multipart/form-data and the parameters still come in with a null value.

Comment: @Josh Can you show pls how you call the action?

Comment: Posted an update.

Comment: @Josh I am testing using Postman and everything is working properly. But if you use ApiController attribute try to add some code to startup. See my updated answer. And in your case it is better to use 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  since form-data should be the last choise.

Comment: I fired up a blank web api project and was able to recreate the same problem.  See above.

Comment: Everything works ok at my side.  Your request in fiddler should be like this  POST https://localhost:5001/Blah/Posted HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 37
firstname=firstname&lastname=lastname

Comment: @Josh you have to use key-value pair, not json

Comment: Ah, you are changing body posted.  I am posting a JSON object which is what worked in previous versions of .Net.  My body is {"firstname":"foo","lastname":"bar"} and that used to automatically get interpreted by .Net.