# How to get ASP.NET Core to bind to simple data types

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, asp.net-core-7.0

I am in the process of migrating a medium-sized .NET 4, ASP.NET MVC (old) application to .NET 7, ASP.NET Core MVC (new).

I have a quite a few controllers with action methods that use simple types for data binding.

```csharp
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...

    public ActionResult Foo(string bar)
    {
        return Content(bar);
    }

    ...
    }
}
```

To the old ASP.NET MVC, I can POST JSON like this with (`content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`):

```
{ "bar": "BAZ" }
```

I use this test harness to test but in reality the requests comes from the frontend part of the system that I prefer to change as  little as possible during the migration.

```csharp
var client = new HttpClient();
var content =  new  StringContent("{ \"bar\": \"BAZ\" }", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json", "utf-8"));
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5261/Home/Foo", content);
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

It will bind correctly to the method parameter and return BAZ as I expect.

If I try to run the same controller under ASP.NET Core MVC, the `bar` parameter is always null. I have tried adding `[HttpPost]` and `[FromBody]` but the only thing that  seems to be working is to create a complex type with string bar as a property and adding `[FromBody]`. I've also tried decorating the controller with `[ApiControllerAttribute]`.

Walking through all controllers and adding complex types where needed is something that I would prefer to avoid since it will be a quite large undertaking, also am not so fond of the idea of creating a lot of "useless" types.

Is there any way to access a part of the JSON input as a simple type like in the old version?

Comment: Can you try decorating your controller with `[ApiControllerAttribute]`?

Comment: Decorating the controller with `[ApiControllerAttribute]` yields the follwing error: {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"errors":{"$":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."],"bar":["The bar field is required."]},"traceId":"00-bfbd08863a2b790d8e1114db3f946f46-5b4b384ac9856862-00"}

Comment: Have you got `[Consumes("application/json")]` on your controller or method?

Comment: This SO question/answer is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70027239/binding-net-core-json-to-simple-parameters

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What kind of data are you trying to post? Are you posting data from the form or using ajax ? To help you we need to the code you use to call  the controller action

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all. What kind of data are you trying to post? Are you posting data from the form or using javascript or maybe httpclient ? To help you we need to the code you use to call the controller action.  For example, I don't understand why do you need POST json, just to send one string. You can use another content form.  But if you realy need  json and don't want  for some reason create the special class, the simplest way would be if change only server side

```
 public ActionResult Foo([FromBody]Dictionary<string,string> dict)
  {
     var bar = dict["bar"];
      return Content(bar);
  }
```

UPDATE

You can leave a server side as it is and change only the client side content. Instead of json you can use application/x-www-form-urlencoded  content type for example and create key value pairs on the client side.

```
 var val = JObject.Parse("{ \"bar\": \"BAZ\" }").Properties()
    .Select(jo => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(jo.Name, (string) jo.Value));

//or just
var val = new [] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bar", "Baz") };
       
var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5261/Home/Foo",
                                         new FormUrlEncodedContent(val) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have provided example JSON data that works in old .NET but not in the new. I have added a paragraph about not changing the frontend as I would like to change as little as possible in the migration process.

Using the dictionary approach works but it will complicate the code in the action methods. Right now the most promising path is to Implement a ValueProviderFactory to replicate the functionality that was in old .NET.